# Setting up Code Blocks with Irrlicht ubuntu 18.04: Trying to compile examples; many issues

Tags: dependencies, compiling, code-blocks

I want to learn to make a game with irrlicht 3d engine and code blocks/c++. I installed codeblocks, I followed Irrlicht instructions from various sources, My current problems are below.

These are the Build Messages from code blocks when trying to compile the code from irrlicht 03.CustomSceneNode main.cpp in examples after following the instructions in this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1n9mWN60xqI  :

```
===============================================================

Build: Debug in testing (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)

ld cannot find -lIrrlicht

ld cannot find -lGL

ld cannot find -lGLU

ld cannot find -lIrrlicht

ld cannot find -lXxf86vn

ld cannot find -lGL

error: ld returned 1 exit status|

Build failed: 7 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|

===============================================================
```

I can’t figure out how to fix the “ld cannot find -lIrrlicht” problem.
Irrlicht was set up twice. The first time with the download from their site, the second through terminal on instructions I found in a forum (I forget where), I ran make on both of them and set them up in code block with the instructions in the video.

Also, I’m clearly missing the necessary openGL libraries or their not linked right, but I can’t install them. When I try, this is the terminal output:

===============================================================

```
~$ sudo apt-get install libgl-dev

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libgl1-mesa-dev' instead of 'libgl-dev'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-dev : Depends: libglvnd-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

===============================================================

I already installed the following libraries:
`libxxf86vm-dev`
`libxcomposite-dev`
`mesa-common-dev`, which I removed before trying again with the GL library, but that didn’t change anything.

I want to get codeblocks set ups to the point where I can compile the example programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I recommend to download all the stuff from apt-repositories starting from  Irrlicht:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential libirrlicht-doc libirrlicht-dev \
libxxf86vm-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libxcursor-dev
```

If you need to compile stuff related to it you should install its build-dependencies too - at first enable *Source Code* repositories in *Software and Updates* (`software-properties-gtk`) and then:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep libirrlicht-dev
```

I do not have time to watch YouTube video.

So I recommend to compile some examples.  I hope it does not matter - from terminal or from CodeBlocks... You can start with [Official Tutorials](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/?page_id=291).

---

Your example may be used as follows:

```
cp -ar /usr/share/doc/libirrlicht-doc/examples ~/irrlicht-examples
cd ~/irrlicht-examples/03.CustomSceneNode
gunzip *.gz
ln -s /usr/include/irrlicht ../../include
codeblocks CustomSceneNode.cbp
```

In CodeBlocks press <kbd>F9</kbd> for *Build and Run*. After compilation select Linux target and click OK.

[image: Irrlicht example 03 - menu]

and then <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> for OpenGL and get demo screen

[image: Irrlicht example 03 - demo]

The method above was tested on clean Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.

Comment: Istill ahve problems with the opengl:  The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-dev : Depends: libglvnd-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy libglvnd-dev libgl1-mesa-dev` to the question above. Also make sure that you have enabled all repositories (check *Software and Updates*) and updates (on *Updates* tab).

Comment: Did you forget to run `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: I enabled Source code and updates in software and updates. It seems to have worked. The libraries installed now, I'm going to try to compile the example and will post results. apt-cache policy libglvnd-dev libgl1-mesa-dev Showed nothing was installed until I enabled source code and updates and updated, then I ran your apt-get line. Now it shows them installed (will post text later). Thanks.

Comment: All was good until I got to the line 'code' codeblocks CustomSceneNode.cbp 'code'   output was: Gtk-Message: 14:15:47.586: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Starting Code::Blocks Release 16.01  rev 10692 2017-09-30, 18:21:54 - wx3.0.3 (Linux, unicode) - 64 bit

Comment: I think it is just warning. Are you running MATE 18.04? Is it clean installation of upgrade?

Comment: And, when i tried to compile in code blocks, I got the 1 error: ld cannot find -lXxf86vn

Comment: I am running MATE desktop environment in a normal install of Ubuntu 18.04 (added it through apt-get)

Comment: There is no Xxf86vn, but we have already installed Xxf86vm (`libxxf86vm-dev` package). Please execute carefully all commands from my answer. I have just checked on clean Ubuntu MATE 18.04.1 - they work as expected. Canberra may be fixed by `sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk3-module libcanberra-gtk-module`.

Comment: The package fix worked as well. (Thanks, it takes a lot of time to find all this stuff). I copied and pasted line by line into the terminal and noticed one I missed earlier: ~$ cd ~/irrlicht-examples/03.CustomSceneNode
levi@levi-EP45-UD3R:~/irrlicht-examples/03.CustomSceneNode$ gunzip *.gz
gzip: *.gz: No such file or directory
I thought it worked the first time I did it but I closed the terminal so I'm not sure.

Comment: Gunzip on second run is not needed as all sources are already unpacked. But `codeblocks CustomSceneNode.cbp` should open CodeBlocks, and then you can click on `<F9>` to build and run. You can use your original method. I listed mine just for proof-of-concept to show that is works.

Comment: Oh, it works now. I had to rerun everything but the gunzip line. It opened, and compiled and is running beautifully. Thank you so much!